# String variable as argument to Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Why is it that this works:

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-ChildItem '\\COMPUTER\folder with spaces'
```

But this does not:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $a = "'\\COMPUTER\folder with spaces'"
PS C:\Users\user> Get-ChildItem $a

Cannot find path 'C:\Users\user\'\COMPUTER\folder with spaces''
because it does not exist
```

How can I use a variable to do something to the effect of the latter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further experiments revealed this solution:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $a = "\\COMPUTER\folder with spaces"
PS C:\Users\user> Get-ChildItem "$a"
```

Answer (score 3):

Nested quotes become part of the string.

- `Get-ChildItem '\\COMPUTER\folder with spaces'`

  This will read the child items from the share `folder with spaces` on the host `COMPUTER`.
- `Get-ChildItem "\\COMPUTER\folder with spaces"`

  This will do the same, but the double quotes also allow you to use variables inside the string, e.g. like this: `"\\$computer\folder with spaces"`.
- `Get-ChildItem "'\\COMPUTER\folder with spaces'"`

  This, however, will look for a file or folder with the literal name `'\\COMPUTER\folder with spaces'` (including the single quotes) in the current working directory on your local computer.